# not able to get map element's functions or properties from Mapbox React Component

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Hi I am new to Mapbox and using mapbox with deckgl

I am using

```
import { Map } from "react-map-gl";
```

I want to get the zoom level of the map at any instance

This is my map component in my return function

```
<Map
  mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
  antialias={true}
  mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
  ref={mapComponentRef}
  onLoad={postLoadHandler}
/>

const postLoadHandler = (mapELement) => {
    console.log(mapELement, mapComponentRef.current);
};
```

where i created mapComponentRef with null as initial value

```
  const mapComponentRef = useRef(null);
```

I was expecting `mapELement` in postLoadHandler to have all the function mentioned here

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map-parameters

but i am not able to find all functions like getZoom is not there ( not limited to that)

This is a screenshot of console.log(mapElement)

[image]

Any help please !!